# how to use multiple mimetypes of image for uiwebview image and attach with email objective c

Tags: objective-c, email, mime-types, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am downloading image from UIWebView with this method

```
NSURL *imgUrl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[DataPassing sharedManager] pageIMGurl]];
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

now I want to send this downloaded or saved or data Image with email using MFMailComposeViewController

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:img mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"mobiletutsImage"];
```

Now issue comes that I don't know the type of downloaded image in 'img', so i can put rite mimeType:@"image/png". What if the downloaded image is jpeg?

how to store multiple mimetypes and check with "img" and then send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to worry about the image type. `UIImagePNGRepresentation` returns the png representation of the `UIImage` object.

If you use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` method to convert your `UIImage` into `NSData`, you should pass @"image/jpg" as mime type.

One more way is in the url, the last component will be image name. Fetch the extension of it and you will come to know the mime type.